# How to make textview background like instagram direct message

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I wanna make my text view is like this

[image: Instagram Direct Message]

i wanna take just background (rounded on edge only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/myEDT"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:hint="Enter Text" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete" />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**button_background**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="50dp" />
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
</shape>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]